# Разбивка текста в две колонки

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Хочу вывести в две колонки:"id | Name", но  никак не получается.

```
const obj = {
  data: [{
    id: "1236",
    name: "Friend name"
  }, {
    id: "1235",
    name: "Friend name"

  }]
}

obj.data.map(x => document.write(x.name))
obj.data.map(y => document.write(y.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

ну вы же сначала выводите все name, потом все id. Выводите сразу name | id

```
const obj = { 
  data: [
    { id: "1236", name: "Friend name" }, 
    { id: "1235", name: "Friend name"}
  ] 
}

obj.data.map(x => {
  document.write(x.name + ' | ' + x.id + '<br>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас сначала выведутся все имена потом все id.
 Поэтому сразу выводим их как пара.

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
 id: "1236",
 name: "Friend name"
  }, {
 id: "1235",
 name: "Friend name"
  }]
}

obj.data.map(x => 
   document.write(x.name + " - " + x.id + "<br>")
);
```

Comment: Я не знаю, как лучше. Просто потом я хочу в name другие имена и отсортировать их по алфавиту. Вот.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так сделать:

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
    id: "1236",
    name: "Friend name"
  }, {
    id: "1235",
    name: "Friend name"

  }]
}

obj.data.map(function(x) {
    var element = document.createElement("p");
        element.innerHTML = `${x.id} | ${x.name}`;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
})
```